# Derivation of Crofton's formula in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: probability, measure-theory, differential-geometry, integral-geometry

I am having trouble deriving Crofton's formula for rectifiable curves in $\mathbb{R}^4$. My approach so far has been as follows. Hyperplanes in $\mathbb{R}^4$ may be given by the data of a real number $r$ and a point $v$ on $S^3$ via $(r,v)\mapsto\{x\,|\,\langle
 x,v\rangle=r\}$. There will be a formula of the form
$$l(\gamma)=C\int_{S^3}
\int_{\mathbb{R}}|\gamma\cap\Pi(r,v)|K(r,v)d\lambda(r)dS(v)$$
for some universal constant $C>0$, where $K(r,v)$ is a function which ensures the right hand side is invariant under rigid motions, $\Pi(r,v)$ is the aforementioned hyperplane associated to the pair $(r,v)$, $d\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $dS$ is the surface measure of $S^3$. We need to calculate $K$ and $C$.

For $K$, we observe that the action of the isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^4$ doesn't distort space (that is, the Jacobian of the left-action of any element in this group is 1). Therefore by the change of variable formula $K$ should be identically 1.

For $C$, it suffices to compute the integral for a simple choice of $\gamma$. I choose $\{0\leq x\leq1\}\cap\{y=z=w=0\}$, a line segment of length 1 on the $x$-axis. Using spherical coordinates
$$x=\cos(\theta),\;y=\sin(\theta)\cos(\phi),\;z=\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\cos(\psi),\;w=\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi)\sin(\psi)$$
where $0\leq\theta,\phi\leq\pi$ and $0\leq\psi<2\pi$, I think the hyperplane $\Pi(r,\theta,\phi,\psi)$ intersects $\gamma$ if and only if $0<|r|<\cos\theta\leq1$, and in this case there is precisely 1 intersection point. Then
\begin{align}
1&=C\int_{S^3}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\gamma\cap\Pi(r,v)|drdS(v)\\&=2C\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}
\int_0^{\infty}|\gamma\cap\Pi(r,v)|r^3\sin^2\theta\sin\phi drd\theta d\phi d\psi\\&=2C\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}
\int_{0}^{\cos\theta}r^3\sin^2\theta\sin\phi drd\theta d\phi d\psi\\&=8C\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}
\int_{0}^{\cos\theta}r^3\sin^2\theta drd\theta\\
&=2C\pi\int_0^{\pi/2}
\cos^4\theta\sin^2\theta d\theta\\
&=\frac{C\pi^2}{16}
\end{align}
implying that $C=16/\pi^2$. Now I believe that Crofton's formula in this context is actually given by
$$l(\gamma)=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\int_{S^3\times\mathbb{R}}|\gamma\cap\Pi(r,v)|d\lambda(r)dS(v)$$
as can be seen [here](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/51327033.pdf) on page 89 for example. I have made an error therefore, but I can't see where it is. I am not even totally sure if the logic in this approach is correct. Any help in identifying either of these things would be much appreciated.

Comment: For what it's worth, the bible of integral geometry, Santaló's *Integral Geometry and Geometric Probability*, gives the constant $C=\dfrac{15}{4\pi}$, if I have not miscalculated. See (14.69) on p. 245. (You have $n=4$, $q=1$, and $r=3$.)